# Java bidimensional array divided by major diagonal

Tags: java, arrays

I'm using a bidimensional array in Java for a checkers game that is like `Tile[8][8]` to represent my board.

That bidimensioanal array (the board) can be divided diagonally by its major diagonal like this:

[image]

The positions that correspond to this are: (0,0); (1,1); (2,2); (3,3); (4,4); (5,5); (6,6); (7,7).

Given two pairs of coordinates (`row_start`, `col_start`) and (`row_final`, `col_final`), I need to understand if each other are in opposite sides (or right on the diagonal itself) of that diagonal line.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Note that the diagonal has subscripts with the same value.  Can you use that as a basis for making a comparison?  Try writing some code and update your question *with the code* if there is still a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will help you see the pattern between x and y:

[image]

To check whether given x,y coordinates fall on the diagonal line from North-West to South-East:

```
public boolean isOnDiagonalLineNW_SE(int x1, int y1){
    return x1 == y1;
}
```

To check whether it is **above** the diagonal line:

```
public boolean isAboveDiagonalLine(int x1, int y1){
    return y1 > x1;
}
```

To check whether it is **below** the diagonal line:

```
public boolean isBelowDiagonalLine(int x1, int y1){
    return x1 > y1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a point `(x, y)`, test if `x > y`.
When coordinate `x` is equals to `y`, the point is over the diagonal. If `x > Y`, he is on the top triangle, else, he is in the low one...

If you test it for both points (start and final), you can check the situation (if they are in opposite side or in the same, for instance)...

Comment: No. Like I said, I want to evaluate pairs of coordinates (row1, col1) and (row2, col2). I want to evaluate if the first pair is above/below the line and then if the second pair is the opposite (or in the line itself).

Comment: It is but I can't figure out how to detect if the pair is above or below without running a huge algorithm like switch-case checking each row and column. I was hopping to find some mathematical calculation to easy the process.

Comment: @jonypera I have a mathematical equation for you, but I am not sure what you actually wants. Can you give a few examples? For the 1st pair of coordinates, you don't have to check whether it is on the diagonal line, but you need to perform this check on the 2nd pair of coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that there is a simple repeating pattern in this concept, that is, all integer numbers that repeat in both the column as well as the row are "on the diagonal"... because it's a square. The minute this is no longer a square, this calculation becomes useless and so it is absolutely not the "best" solution for this problem.

You could just do really simple checks like...

`if(row_start == col_start || row_final == col_final)`. This shows you numbers that are **ON** the diagonal line. Once you know this information then you could say `if(row_start > col_start)` (then you know it's to the right of the diagonal) or `if(row_start < col_start)` (then you know it's to the left of the diagonal line)

If the board isn't a square or "could" be a rectangle, but cannot change after run-time, then a more dynamic approach could also be taken. First you could "discover" the diagonal you want to be remembered as a token placement on the board and store it in an array to remember it. You would use a loop to start at 0,0 and quickly iterate the length and width of the board to find the places you want to be the new diagonal. As you discover each position you would record the values into your array (a 2D array would work but I would suggest an array of objects maybe even enums so that the row/col of each can easily be stored). Now that you know your new diagonal line and have it stored in memory its incredibly easy to verify now if the line is on, above, below or beside the diagonal line. This variable should last the length of the view with this board on it and become a core application state variable in order to maintain a focus on this diagonal line for future rules and whatnot.